# Filter items returned from PHP using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am looking for a way to filter items that I get from the backend. Basically, what I am doing is

```
<div class="items">
   <?php foreach ($items as $item) { 
    <a> $item </a> }
 ?>
</div>
```

Essentially, I am getting a `$items` from the database as an array. This array contains times

```
$items
{
    0 => 12:00:00 
    1 => 13:00:00
    2 => 14:00:00
    3 => 15:00:00
    4 => 09:00:00 }
```

I am looking to filter this printed times by separating them into `morning` which will be from `09:00:00 to 12:00:00` and day from `12:00:00 to 18:00:00`

So, I will have a filter button called Morning, when I click that button I want to just print times ranging from 9 to 12, and if the day button is clicked it will only print times ranging from 13 to 15.

I tried sending filtered items from the backend but it was only slower, as I have lots of times, I think doing this from Javascript/Angular would be much better, but I am unsure exactly how to start. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: you should add the server side code that you are using maybe we can optimize and you can avoid using jquery frontend for large datasets, as it would hang your browser.

Comment: Pushing the filtering to the client isn't going to speed anything up for your users. You should be filtering during the query for optimal performance.

Comment: If I do it from the backend the query goes through a huge list of API methods again, I can filter it just to show those times, but the user has to submit the form again using those filters, and my system will take time to query again. If I do it from the client side, I will just be hiding/filtering the items that are already shown in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the filtering can be done server-side, it is better. However if you want to have a way to do it front-side, you can use the code below.

I consider that you will display your array `items` to the user. If the user clicks on the button `morning` (respectively `afternoon`), items will be filtered to have the values accordingly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var items = "<?php echo $items ?>"; 

var saveItems = items;

$("#morning").on("click", function(){

 items = saveItems.filter(element => element < "12:00:00 ")
})

$("#afternoon").on("click", function(){

 items = saveItems.filter(element => element > "12:00:00")
})
$("#reset").on("click", function(){

 items = saveItems
})
</script>

<button id="morning">Morning </button>
<button id="afternoon">Afternoon </button>
<button id="reset">Reset </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

consider you have an time array like this :

```js
myArray =[
     "12:00:00", 
     "13:00:00",
     "14:00:00",
     "15:00:00",
     "09:00:00"
     ]
var n = myArray.length;     
     
function A(){
  for( var i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    var num =  parseInt(myArray[i].slice(0,2));
    if( 9 <= num && num <= 12 ){
      myArray[i] = myArray[i] + " morning"; 
    }
    else{
      myArray[i] = myArray[i] + " evening"; 
    }
  }
}  
A();
console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach loop in the PHP code, you can set a filter class on each item. Something like:

```
$hour = explode( ':', $item)[0] );
$class = $hour <= 12 : 'morning' : 'day';
echo "<a class='$class' >$item</a>";
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing one way to show/hide these elements on the front end. https://jsfiddle.net/mqcbfuhy/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do any type of client side time display/evaluation/manipulation with javascript then before you spend ages writing custom code you should check out [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). It does pretty much everything you can think of relating to time.